# Some questions on basic linear algebra about dimension and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading some lectures on linear algebra which are on Russian language and few moments have confused me and I was trying to understand them correctly but I failed to do it.

Firstly, let me give you some preliminary definitions and theorems from my lectures:

> **Definition:** A vector space $V$ is called *finite-dimensional*, if it has a basis consisting of finitely many vectors. Otherwise, we call
>   the space to be *infinite-dimensional*.
>
> **Theorem:** In finite-dimensional vector space each basis has the same number of vectors.
>
> The proof of this theorem is based on the following lemma:
>
> **Lemma:** Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_m\}$ and $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ be two linearly independent system of vectors such that the second system is
>   contained in the linear span of the first. Then $n\leq m$.
>
> **Definition:** The dimension of finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is the number of elements in each basis of $V$. If $V$ is
>   infinite-dimensional, then we write $\dim V =\infty$.

Then he is proving the following statement which confuses me.

> **Statement:** Subspace $W$ of finite-dimensional space $V$ is finite-dimensional and $\dim W\leq \dim V$.
>
> *Proof:* Since $V$ is finite-dimensional then $\dim V=m$ and let $\{e_1,\dots,e_m\}$ basis of $V$. Suppose that $\dim W>m$ then $W$
>   contains linearly independent vectors $f_1,\dots,f_n$ with $n>m$. Then
>   $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}\subset \langle e_1,\dots,e_m\rangle=V.$ But this
>   contradicts to the above lemma. Hence $\dim W\leq \dim V$.

I understood the idea of the proof but cannot understand some technical moments.

*Question 1:* If $\dim W>m$ then why $W$ contains linearly independent vectors $f_1,\dots,f_n$ with $n>m$. Intuitively I know this but can anyone show it rigorously?

*Question 2 (sorry for stupid question):* Suppose we have shown that $\dim W\leq \dim V$ then how it follows that $W$ is also finite-dimensional?

Comment: If there were not $n$ linearly independent vectors in $W$, then you would take as many as you could and they would have to span $W$ (i.e. would be a basis with less than or equal to $m$ elements).

Comment: For question 2, if $\dim{W} = \infty$ that would be bigger than $\dim{V}$.

Comment: Do you have the definition "A vector space is $n$-dimensional if it has a basis with $n$ elements"?

Comment: @MorganRodgers, to be honest I didn't understand your first comment. Could you explain it one more time?

Comment: Sure, if you take a collection of linearly independent vectors in $W$, starting with a single vector, then at each step either 1: the collection you have spans all of $W$, and so is a basis for $W$ or 2: they don't span all of $W$ so you can add a vector to get a larger collection of linearly independent vectors. You just do this until you have more than $n$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, I cannot get what do you mean at all. Look we have that $\dim W>m$, right? But assume that $W$ does not contain $n$ linearly independent vectors with $n>m$. It means that maximum number of linearly independent vectors is at most $m$, right? I think that in order to continue this reasoning we have to assume that each vector space has a basis.

Comment: @ZFR Any finite-dimensional vector space has a basis. But the whole point of this method of argument is that you cannot assume that $W$ is finite-dimensional (in other words, you cannot assume that $W$ has a basis).

Comment: @MorganRodgers, could you give a separate answer? Because to be honest I do not follow your reasoning at all. I would be very grateful of you can write in more clear way.

Comment: "In Russian" doesn't mean that you shouldn't cite it :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg, "Lectures in linear algebra"by T.E.Panov

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Suppose $\dim W > m$. By your second definition, the dimension of a finite-dimensional vector space is the number of elements of each basis of this vector space. This surelly works for vector subspaces too. So, if $W$ is finite dimensional, each basis of $W$ has more than $m$ elements. But we know that the elements of a basis must be linearly independent, by the definition of a basis. So, we conclude that $W$ contains linearly independent vectors $f_{1},...,f_{n}$, for some $n>m$. If $W$ is infinite-dimensional, the statement still holds. To see this, suppose that there is no set of linearly independent vectors $f_{1},...,f_{n}$ in $W$. Then, every set of $n$ vectors is linearly dependent, and thus $\dim W < n$, which contradicts the fact that $W$ is infinite-dimensional.

Question 2: If $\dim W \le \dim V$ then $\dim W \le m$, since $m = \dim V$. Thus, the dimension of $W$ must be, at most, equal to $m$, which is a finite number. It follows that $W$ is finite-dimensional, once its dimension if finite.

Comment: Regarding question 1: You said "by your second definition.." but what if $W$ is infinite-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, I was editing it! haha thanks!

Comment: Regarding question 2: You have shown that $\dim W\leq m$ but how it follows that $W$ is finite-dimensional by these definitions?

Comment: Because every basis of $W$ must have at most $m$ vectors, and then you apply your second definition again.

Comment: It is still not so clear to me. You said that each basis of $W$ must have at most $m$ vectors. Why? What if some basis has $>m$ vectors.

Comment: This is not possible. Suppose it was true, and $W$ have a basis with $n>m$ elements. Then, by your second definition, the dimension of $W$ is $n>m$, so $\dim W$ is not $\le m$.

Comment: Remember that every basis must have the same number of elements.

Comment: Every basis have the same number of elements in FINITE-dimensional space. This is what I know.

Comment: Yes yes, I was adding this comment to the former.

Comment: You know i still cannot understand your reasoning. Sorry but it looks quite messy and does not coincode with those definitions

Comment: You have to understand the concept of a basis. The dimension of a (finite-dimensional) vector space is just the number of elements of each of its basis. How can one have $\dim W \le m$ and a basis vector with more than $m$ elements?

Comment: Regarding second question you said id $W$ have a basis with $n>m$ vectors. But it could infinitely many vectors.

Comment: Regarding your last comment: i am agree with this provided that $W$ is finite-dimensional. But in our case we have to show thatvit is finite-dimensional. Please read more carefully

Comment: Your question says:
Question 2 (sorry for stupid question): Suppose we have shown that dimW≤dimV then how it follows that W is also finite-dimensional?

Comment: So, I'm supposing we have shown $\dim W \le \dim V$, right?

Comment: @MorganRodgers yes, it is exaclty that. It is ZFR who does not agree with that!

Comment: I am learning linear algebra for the first time and I guess it is ok that i am quite stupid at that moment. Could we discuss it in chat?

Comment: @ZFR is this question for me? If it is, we can discuss it on a chat

Comment: @Willy.K, yeah I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: hm, dont know. Never used this here. Let me check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100950/discussion-between-zfr-and-willy-k).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if $n=\dim W$ then $n$ is the number of elements in (any) a basis of $W$.

Suppose $W \subset V$ and $p=\dim V $ is finite. Let $n=\dim W$, then there is a basis $b_1,...,b_n$ for $W$.

If $V \setminus W$ is non empty we can find some $b_{n+1} \in V \setminus W$ and the
resulting collection $b_1,...,b_{n+1}$ is linearly independent.

We can continue this process (with $\operatorname{sp} \{b_1,...,b_{n+1} \}$ in place of $W$) a finite number of times. When it terminates, the resulting collection will be a basis of $V$ from which it follows that
$n \le p$.